# Generic related set in django?

Tags: django, orm, models

I have a models like this for storing GUI data for Applications:

```
class Application(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
   gui = models.ForeignKey(GuiPanel)

class GuiPanel(models.Model):
   dimensions = models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField(max_length=16, help_text='Width,Height')
   backgroundImage = models.ImageField(upload_to='guiImages/', blank=True) 

class GuiComponent(models.Model):
   guiPanel = models.ForeignKey(GuiPanel)
   position = models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField(max_length=16) # x,y position
   controlId = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True) # optional

   class meta:
       abstract = True

class RotaryDial(GuiComponent): 
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to='guiImages/')
   angleRange = models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField(max_length=16, help_text='startAngle,endAngle')
   valueRange = models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField(max_length=16, help_text='startVal,endVal)

class Toggle(GuiComponent): # we always just use 0 and 1 for its value
   onImage = models.ImageField(upload_to='guiImages/')
   offImage = models.ImageField(upload_to='guiImages/')
```

So each Application has a GuiPanel and this has a height, width, a background image, and  implicitly has a set of GuiComponents (which for now has two subclasses but may have more in future).

So I might fetch an Application with all its gui data with something like this:

```
Application.objects.prefetch_related('gui', 'gui__rotarydial_set', 'gui__toggle_set').get(pk=1)
```

This is a little tedious because there will be about 6 subclasses and I may add more in the future.

Or if I used a non-abstract model for GuiPanel, I could do this:

```
Application.objects.prefetch_related('gui', 'gui__guicomponent_set').get(pk=1)
```

Then I could introspect on the actual subclass of each instance in the guicomponent_set by using hasattr.

First of all, is the overall model ok or could it be improved? And finally, which of the options above (abstract vs non-abstract) is better in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the cleanest way would be without abstract classes. As suggested in django documentation you should have a table for the base class (with base attributes) and a table for each derived class with a OneToOne key to the base class and attributes of the derived class.

Comment: What if I simply had a single GuiComponent table with many optional fields and a component_type? I could simply have a separate form for each type and constrain the GuiComponent.save() method to enforce fields that are required for a given type.